# How Dataset synchronization happens?

Tags: ado.net, dataset

This question has been asked in one of the interviews I have attended recently. Suppose we have a dataset. We know that it(dataset) works in disconnected mode. Now we have picked up the necessary data from the database into the dataset by using the dataadapter and filled up the UI.
Suppose one user (say user1) is making some update in the UI which will be later save to the database via the dataset and some other user (say user 2) has already modified the data into the database.

The question is then how come the dataset come to know at what point the data has been modified? that is how synchronization happens in the dataset?

In other word, user1 is unware that user2 has modified some record in the database. But somehow the dataset needs to be updated about the same. How can this happen?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One way to work around optimistic concurrency issues in ADO 
is to lock the records your DataSet retrieves as soon as 
the edit operation begins. This strategy is known as 
pessimistic locking. Long-duration locks generally lead to 
poor database performance and contention problems, but in 
situations where an application cannot tolerate having 
records changed while it is updating them, pessimistic 
locking may be necessary.

With ADO, it's relatively easy to use a pessimistic locking 
scheme. In ADO.NET, it's somewhat more difficult to set up, 
but you can still use pessimistic locking in your 
applications. However, just because you can do something 
doesn’t mean you should do it all the time—what I’m about 
to explain should be used only when absolutely necessary.

The basics steps for pessimistic locking are as follows:

```
  1) Create a transaction with an IsolationLevel of RepeatableRead.

  2) Set the DataAdapter’s SelectCommand property to use the transaction you created.

  3) Make the changes to the data.

  4) Set DataAdapter’s Insert, Update, and Delete command properties to use the transaction you created.

  5) Call the DataAdapter’s Update method.

  6) Commit the transaction.
```